Permission denied when trying to clone pantheon git repo
I'm trying to clone the git repo of my site from pantheon using the clone command they've provided but its throwing this error
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I've signed into pantheon using sso and I've set the same email as git global config on my laptop but I'm still facing this error.

For the ten thousandth time: user.name has nothing to do with authentication. NOT. A. THING.

Cloning the git repo requires configuring an SSH key— Password authentication for SSH/SFTP was removed from Pantheon recently. Details can be found here.
SSH Keys can be added either in the dashboard, or with Terminus, the Pantheon CLI.

worked like a charm! thank you so much
